# Mapping external data to tags via term_id

Tags: tags

I'm looking at migrating a custom CMS with about 40k posts and about 100k tags into WP. The site covers news about the concert industry and will use tags as artist names associated with each post.

There will be external APIs to pull in proprietary images and tour dates for each artist, and they'll need to map to a term_id for the tag which will be the artist name. Internally, a lookup table will need to map against the term_id to generate the API hooks and commerce links.

The question is whether a taxonomy within WP--mapping a tag to several columns of associated content hooks--is the best way to come at this, or should this become an external tag-mapping plugin that works outside the WP table structure from the outset.

Comment: You got 2.5x more tags than posts?

Comment: A news story can reference multiple artists, particularly if it's about a festival or multi-act tour.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would question if your "tags" should be imported as *WordPress* tags in first place.

In WordPress taxonomies are strictly grouping mechanism. They have their own database schema (relatively more convoluted one) and don't support meta data out of the box.

I would at least consider importing artists as Custom Post Type.

Comment: THanks, I hadn't considered that approach. I'll explore. 

For the moment, I'm mostly trying to assess whether there's more heavy lifting involved in getting this artist/internal story/external mapping situation constructed in WordPress or Drupal. Preference would be WordPress, but this is a high-level requirement.